# bpy.data.libraries.write not working?

Tags: python, scripting

I want to save selected objects into a separate .blend file in 2.8.

https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.types.BlendDataLibraries.html
suggests:

```
import bpy

filepath = "//new_library.blend"
data_blocks = set(bpy.context.selected_objects)
bpy.data.libraries.write(filepath, data_blocks)
```

I created a blank scene, added two spheres to it and saved everything.
Afterwards I selected them both and let the script run through: A ".blend" file gets created, however it doesn't contain anything.

I re downloaded 2.79 and got the same result. So I am unsure where the problem lies and don't want to file a bug report immediately without having some outside input. Could somebody please clarify things for me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Check the data**

Chances are   the objects are saved to the library blend, . but are not linked to any scene, or collection, hence the file appears empty when opened.

Check the library files `bpy.data.objects` collection to confirm.

Consider adding the scene datablock to the library.

Comment: I went ahead and foolishly did file a bug report and Brecht sorted it out in 5 minutes... https://developer.blender.org/T60792
Indeed, I needed to add the scene datablock AND the collections aswell.
So in the end it seems I did not get the documentation right... I will update my initial answer once I got it to work! Thank you for responding!

Comment: When adding "bpy.context.scene" to the datablock, everything within the scene gets saved to the new file, not only the selection. (So it basically overrides "bpy.context.selected_objects") I tried to make some kind of context override with "ctx = bpy.context.scene.copy()", but this makes a new scene. I want the objects to stay on "bpy.data.scenes['Scene']", not move to "bpy.data.scenes['Scene.001']", however. I think I am missing something here... :(

Comment: Yeah, just like the meshes (or data part) come with the objects written to lib, so will  objects linked to scene written to lib.  To write to lib with scene and only selected objects could  unlink unselected scene.objects, write scene, re-link.   or .. run a bg script on file if no scene make one link objects to it, .. or ..  hmmm   Perhaps write up a new question explaining that you want to use libraries.write to  save scene with  only selected objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:
Create new scene named « Scene » (the original takes an new name:
« Scene.001 », but you can rename it later)

Link your selected_object to « Scene » and then:

data_blocks=bpy.context.scene
Etc…

Delete « Scene »
Rename « Scene.001 » as « Scene »

Comment: thank you for the answer! unfortunately I do not get to code much for blender at the moment, so I can not really confirm anything. as far as I remember though, the way to go was to indeed make a new scene and then save the whole scene as a new file. I still think its a messy workaround, though, and would still try to avoid it. But thanks anyways for the effort!