# How to pack data into .blend with bpy.data.libraries.write

Tags: python

I have noticed that it is a discourse of which one speaks little, the correct way to write a .blend file and save objects etc is for example

```
data_blocks = set(bpy.context.selected_objects)
bpy.data.libraries.write("my blendfile dir", data_blocks)
```

But I noticed that for example my models, if I move the file to another computer, the materials are not displayed (purple object)
I was wondering if there was a way to "Pack into .blend" through the script like:
bpy.data.libraries.write(#pack into blend = True)

I need this for create a .blend file that has textures and images packed
without open new .blend file , "write" method think is incomplete because if i delete image or texture new .blend file loose the images/textures

Comment: Someone asked about it and [tis is the answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129592/bpy-data-libraries-write-not-working)that was okayed.

Comment: Thanks for linking. I still think that the problem (as Pastrokkio correctly identified) is the packing. He's not complaining about models not showing up, but about texture files not being present. I kind of think the linking to the scene is the difference between a library file and a "normal" blender file. You can still import the objects fine from the library because they will be linked on import. Also I was wrong about needing to add more data: The scripts works just fine with what Pastrokkio has written if you just add the pack/unpack stuff.

Comment: I want to clarify that currently the object I write in the .blender file has all the textures, nodes, and images, but they are not packed, the problem is if i delete image folder or texture folder, i want pack the image into new file

Comment: @Lukasz-40sth this is not my problem , the objects have all in new file, the problem is Pack the image into new file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Edit:

Actually the assumption on what data gets saved was wrong

```
data_blocks = set(bpy.context.selected_objects)
```

is enough to get all the linked materials, nodes etc.

The script to pack the texture images works just by

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.file.pack_all() #Tells blender to pack images into the file on save
data_blocks = {*bpy.context.selected_objects, }
bpy.data.libraries.write("my blendfile dir", data_blocks, compress=True)
bpy.ops.file.unpack_all() #Tells blender not to pack images into the file on save
```

The option compress=True adds compression to the library file.

### The Problem

I think the selected_objects data only includes the data of the linked object:

- If it is a lamp it will contain brightness type etc
- If it is a mesh it will contain the vertices, faces and the **link/name** to the materials assignes but **NOT** the material/nodegroups/textures itself.

Also the Images need to be packed

### The Research

Taking a look at the api docs:

https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_1/bpy.types.BlendDataLibraries.html

> ```
> import bpy
>
> filepath = "//new_library.blend"
>
> # write selected objects and their data to a blend file
> data_blocks = set(bpy.context.selected_objects)
> bpy.data.libraries.write(filepath, data_blocks)
>
>
> # write all meshes starting with a capital letter and
> # set them with fake-user enabled so they aren't lost on re-saving
> data_blocks = {mesh for mesh in bpy.data.meshes if mesh.name[:1].isupper()}
> bpy.data.libraries.write(filepath, data_blocks, fake_user=True)
>
>
> # write all materials, textures and node groups to a library
> data_blocks = {*bpy.data.materials, *bpy.data.textures, *bpy.data.node_groups}
> bpy.data.libraries.write(filepath, data_blocks, compress=True)
> ```

### The Solution?

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.file.pack_all() #Pack all images into the file
data_blocks = {*bpy.context.selected_objects, 
*bpy.data.images, 
*bpy.data.materials, 
*bpy.data.textures, 
*bpy.data.node_groups }
bpy.data.libraries.write("my blendfile dir", data_blocks, compress=True)
bpy.ops.file.unpack_all() #Will unpack ALL files in the current file.
```

If the pack_all() command does not  work or you don't want it, I think you could loop over all the images and pack them individually:

```
for image in bpy.data.images:
    image.pack()
```

I tested the code on packing images (as images) and for me at least it works

Comment: This code pack into another .blend file?

Comment: I'm 90% sure it does. To test, I started from a non saved startup file, added an image and created a library file. As the library file gets completely rewritten every time and the file was present in the library file this worked. I'll quickly recheck! Tested, worked.

Comment: it's important to don't  pack in current open .blend file

Comment: Ah ok, then I need to modify to unpack after the library file is created. Are there already files packed in the current file that shouldn't be unpacked?

Comment: It must compress them in the destination file. The current .blend file may also have uncompressed images. I need it to work regardless of whether they are compressed or not

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly: I am quite certain, blender doesn't do any compression (unless its lossless) if you save a file. I am not aware of a function that allows you to use some kind of proxy images. Of course the images the render operates at are uncompressed in memory, but should never bet touched in storage.

Comment: Need to pack from script the object with image etc from .write , i don't want open the new file,Otherwise I would have done it manually since the option exists in blender

Comment: I just tested the script again: With the minimal data_blocks = set(bpy.context.selected_objects). Blender saves the ONLY the textures connected to these (selected) Objects into the library file. To test it I created 2 objects with different textures. If selecting only one, only the texture used is saved to the library.   The pack_all doesn't do anything on it's own except to tell blender to include the external images on the next save.

Comment: That is the problem, i want pack image into my new .blend file

Comment: The this should solve it. Writing the library file with packing enabled tells blender to write the images as well! Basically bpy.ops.file.pack_all() behaves somewhat like a libraries.write(**, pack=True) option (which unfortunately does not exist/ is not documented).

Comment: I try but not work the .blend file created are not packed

Comment: I tested it with the internal also. You are aware, that with data_blocks = {*bpy.context.selected_objects, }, it will export the materials only for the selected objects. If you need to export for all objects in the scene, you need to either select all or change to the other script. Also you might be able to test with a new file, If the image gets packed the library file is much bigger.

Comment: Yes, but this is not the problem to be solved, it is like packing, the question is very specific, I apologize for being frank but I am looking for a specific answer

Comment: Exuse me for the confusion ,your code is right , that solve the problem , now have to get the status of pack option from preference

Comment: Nice to hear that it worked. Can you maybe formulate a new question about the status. You can check individual files by the answer given https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/93413. When you loop over all the images as the last code in my answer, you can check which are packed and which aren't. Once again blender has no global "all" packed or "all unpacked" because the pack_all() just sets a flag to pack on the next save action, it doesn't pack anything on its own.